# How not to lose messages from Kafka when database is offline

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, microservices, spring-kafka

I am developing microservice which consumes messages from Kaffka then processes this messages and stores output to MongoDB

I am new to kafka and I encounter some problem with losing messages.

Scenario is pretty easy:

In case of mongoDB being offline microservice recieves a message then trying to save output to Mongo then I get error that says mongo is offline and message is lost.

My question is there is any mechanism in kafka that stops sending messages in that case. Should manually commit offset in Kafka ? What are best practices to handle error in Kafka consumers?

Answer (score 2):

For such kind of scenario you should manually commit the offset. Commit offset only if your message processing successful. You commit it like below.  However you should note that messages have ttl hence messages get automatically deleted from kafka broker after ttl elapse.

```
consumer.commitSync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think rather than making commit manually, you should use Kafka Streams and Kafka Connect. Managing transaction between two systems: Apache Kafka and MongoDB might be not so easy, so better use already developed and tested tools (You can read more about Kafka Connect:  https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connect, https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html)

Your scenario might be something like this:

- Process your message using [Kafka Streams](https://kafka.apache.org/21/documentation/streams/) and send result to new
  topic (Kafka Streams support exactly-once semantics)
- Use Kafka Connect (Sink connector) to save data in MongoDB https://www.confluent.io/connector/kafka-connect-mongodb-sink/

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do this by using `pause` and `resume` methods on `MessageListenerContainer` (But you have to use spring kafka > 2.1.x) [spring-kafka-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/MessageListenerContainer.html)

**@KafkaListener Lifecycle Management**

> The listener containers created for `@KafkaListener` annotations are not beans in the application context. Instead, they are registered with an infrastructure bean of type `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry`. This bean is automatically declared by the framework and manages the containers' lifecycles; it will auto-start any containers that have `autoStartup` set to `true`.

So Autowire `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` registry endpoint in the application

```
@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
```

Get the `MessageListenerContainer` from registry [spring-kafka-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/config/KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.html#getListenerContainer-java.lang.String-)

```
public MessageListenerContainer getListenerContainer(java.lang.String id)
```

> Return the MessageListenerContainer with the specified id or null if no such container exists.

**Parameters:**

> id - the id of the container

On `MessageListenerContainer` you can use `pause` or `resume` methods [spring-kafka-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/MessageListenerContainer.html)

**default void pause()**

> Pause this container before the next poll().

**default void resume()**

> Resume this container, if paused, after the next poll().